# VBA - spontaneous 'Excel cant insert new cells' error

Tags: excel, vba

I have been working on a very large macro.

I put the project down for 2 days to work on other things.

I picked it back up, and now I get a 1004 runtime error:

> Microsoft Excel can't insert new cells because it would push non-empty
>   cells off the end of the worksheet. These cells might appear empty but
>   have blank values, some formatting, or a formula. Delete enough rows
>   or columns to make room for what you want to insert and try again.

The error presents here in the code:

```
    Sub Initial_Setup()

    'Create Transform Tab

        Sheets.Add Before:=Worksheets("Lists")
        ActiveSheet.Name = "Transform"

    'Copy Raw Data Over

        Sheets("Sitedata").Select
        Cells.Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Transform").Select
        Range("A1").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False

    Columns("A").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

Ive researched this and causes range from hidden characters to autofills to freeze panes any more.

Here is the kicker, this isn't the only place im now getting this error. It doesn't matter the method of moving the data. Paste Special, VBA treats all pasted cells as non-empty cells. Range("A1").Value = Range("A1").Value, VBA treats all pasted cells as non-empty cells.

If I do a =Len() test, its 0 characters. If I do a =IF(a1="","x","") test its "x". If I do =CountA(), I get a 1. Ctrl+end takes me to AA3086, the end of the actual dataset and not by far the furthest column to the right.

The workaround is to try to change "Cells.Select" to a more targeted reference, but that will be the start of a ton of patching in different places.

Has anyone else experienced something like this, or have they been experiencing it in the past couple days?

Thanks,

Comment: Nothing like this ?: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2403-excel-change-default-template.html#sheet

Comment: It would help if you could share a workbook which replicates the problem (just needs the code above and some dummy data)

Comment: Thanks for this. I got home from work, plopped the workbook onto my personal computer, and kicked off the macro, and it still works like a charm. So that means something happened in my companies network 2 days ago that gimped VBA. Your link gives me a first lead to try to trace down what is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error message means exactly what it says. As long as your macro inserts rows, it'll trigger that message.  If you try it on a brand new sheet, it won't give you any problems, will it?

Comment: While you arent wrong, I dont understand how a paste values of an empty cell is introducing a null. Isn't one of the purposes of Paste Values to not do that? Also, I cannot for the life of me figure out what I could have done to take it from working fine 2 days ago to not working now on a copy of the file that I'm pulling from an email and was working when I sent it. Really trying to find a way to not need to functionally rewrite it all to factor for this error out of nowhere.

Comment: If there is "something" in your sheet that causes this, there is a risk that you'll copy that something if you create a copy of your workbook. If you instead recreate your workbook by copying chunks it might work.
Also, you mention "introducing a null" in your reply, but I can see anything related to that in your original question

Comment: Either an Excel update came out and changed something, or im just going insane. I didnt say "Introducing a null", but what else has a len of 0, identifies as "", and has a CountA return of 1?

Comment: I read you. One last idea. Select all data to the right of your dataset and remove all formatting. Then do the same for all data below your dataset and do the same.

Comment: Just commented out what is before the insert command, deleted the entire columns and the entire rows to the right of and below AA3086, ran the insert, same error. This makes no sense to me.